# Merge two excel spreadsheets with common column

Tags: excel-formula

I have one excel spreadsheet with 2 workbooks

The first workbook contains a list of products in one column with an SKU number in the next

The second worksheet contains a list of orders. The only way I know what product has been ordered is by the SKU shown on the second worksheet.

Is there a way to have excel find the original product name on the second worksheet based on the SKU and product name data in the first worksheet

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of how your worksheets look like? Then I'd be able to draft a quick formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the =Concatenate function to combine the product + SKU values on each sheet. This will give you a common key on each sheet. You can then Vlookup the information from one sheet to the other.